# how to fire loadmore after fetching and showing every 100 records from realm

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

Realm recyclerview in following address: [realmrecyclerview](https://github.com/thorbenprimke/realm-recyclerview) has the loadmore feature and there is a example project which creates a 60 realm object then query realm and set the results of the query to recyclerview's adapter. after scrolling the recyclerview to end onloadmore listner get fired in loadmore function another async method get called which creates 60 more object and save to realm, then recyclerview shows the new objects.
I want to use this loadmore functionality to paginate the big dataset query.I tried to query in the onloadmore function but the adapter did not refereshed with new query results. but when I recreated the adapter and set to recyclerview it was working.

Comment: you dont need any "loadmore" feature when reading from a local database: all you need is an adapter that loads your data on demand like https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/master/adapters/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmRecyclerViewAdapter.java

Comment: You don't *need* pagination with RealmResults, because its elements are lazy-evaluated. Just use `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`.

Comment: I used RealmRecyclerView and RealmRecyclerViewAdapter to query and show 50k records which took 4-5 seconds on Galaxy S4-mini with api 17. Querying and getting RealmResults is instant but loading data to recyclerview takes time. spite the use of async query sometimes UI thread get blocked before loading data which I don't like. I used progressdialoge before loading data. Am I on the right track?

Comment: how much time takes getting first 10 items of `RealmResults`?

Comment: results are shown suddenly after get loaded to recyclerview not gradually.I don't measured the loading of first 10 items

Comment: `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` is an abstract class, what does your implementation look like?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my RealmRecyclerView which extends RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public class QuoteRecyclerViewAdapter extends RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter<QuoteModel,
            QuoteRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        public QuoteRecyclerViewAdapter(
                Context context,
                RealmResults<QuoteModel> realmResults,
                boolean automaticUpdate,
                boolean animateIdType,
                String animateExtraColumnName) {
            super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate, animateIdType, animateExtraColumnName);
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RealmViewHolder {

            public FrameLayout container;

            public TextView quoteTextView;

            public TextView footerTextView;

            public ViewHolder(FrameLayout container) {
                super(container);
                this.container = container;
                this.quoteTextView = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.quote_text_view);
                this.footerTextView = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.footer_text_view);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateRealmViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, viewGroup, false);
            return new ViewHolder((FrameLayout) v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindRealmViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
            final QuoteModel quoteModel = realmResults.get(position);
            viewHolder.quoteTextView.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (!quoteModel.isValid()) {
                                return;
                            }
                            asyncRemoveQuote(quoteModel.getId());
                        }
                    }
            );
            viewHolder.quoteTextView.setOnLongClickListener(
                    new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                            asyncUpdateQuote(quoteModel.getId());
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
            );
            if (type != null && type.equals("Grid")) {
                viewHolder.container.setBackgroundColor(
                        colors.get((int) (quoteModel.getId() % colors.size())));
            }
            viewHolder.quoteTextView.setText(quoteModel.getQuote());
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindFooterViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.footerTextView.setText("I'm a footer");
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateFooterViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_view, viewGroup, false);
            return new ViewHolder((FrameLayout) v);
        }
    }
```